# ABAP: how to compare three internal tables

Tags: join, compare, abap

I've recently started an apprenticeship and I've received a small project to help checking tables.

The request is that I am supposed to write a report that compares a table to our profit center's standard hierarchy and tells you which entries are the same and which ones are not.

Now, I've only started getting into ABAP and while I've had SQL prior, i'm not exactly good in it. My colleagues are nice but I fear that I'd look like an idiot if I kept asking them how to do this.

What i've done so far is giving the table some records to check in our development system, selecting all records in it and also selecting everything I need from SETLEAF and SETNODE.

```
SELECT * FROM Y_TABLE
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_compare).



SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK set_leaf.
  CONSTANTS:
            SET_CLASS TYPE SETLEAF-SETCLASS VALUE '0102',
            SUB_CLASS TYPE SETLEAF-SUBCLASS VALUE 'D100'.
  PARAMETERS:
   lv_pcnr TYPE SETLEAF-VALFROM,
   setname TYPE SETLEAF-SETNAME.

SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK set_leaf.


TYPES:
BEGIN OF lt_ausgabe,
  SETCLASS TYPE SETLEAF-SETCLASS,
  SUBCLASS TYPE SETLEAF-SUBCLASS,
  VALFROM TYPE SETLEAF-VALFROM,
  SETNAME TYPE SETLEAF-SETNAME,
  END OF lt_ausgabe.

DATA: 
      gt_setleaf TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF lt_ausgabe,
      gt_setnode TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF lt_ausgabe.

SETNODE-SUBSETNAME = SETLEAF-SETNAME.
SETNODE-SETNAME = SETNODE-SUBSETNAME.

FORM build_table_setleaf.
  SELECT *
  FROM SETLEAF
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @gt_setleaf
    WHERE SETCLASS = @set_class AND SUBCLASS = @sub_class AND VALFROM = @lv_pcnr AND SETNAME = @setname.
ENDFORM.

FORM build_table_setnode.
  SELECT *
  FROM SETNODE
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE @gt_setnode
    WHERE SETCLASS = @set_class AND SUBCLASS = @sub_class AND SUBSETNAME = @setname.
ENDFORM.
```

I've changed the table name and the constant values because I don't know how much of them I can share.
Now I want to compare these tables and well, do what the request asked for. But I don't really understand how to do this. The code above may not be the way to solve this at all..

I'm sorry in advance if any of this sounds off, I would ask in my own language if.. my people weren't known for being unhelpful and rude when asking code-related stuff.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not trivial so you should ask your skilled colleagues. Before going into ABAP language, you should first ask for real test cases and expected results, then think about the "algorithm" (usually language-agnostic). It's not so trivial because it's not just tables, it's hierarchies. As it is first not an ABAP question, please provide the above missing information.

Comment: `that compares a table to our profit center's standard hierarchy` that looks like functional custom requirement. We know nothing neither about the structure of your tables (which you obviusly obfuscated in the above snippet) nor about what is the standard hierarchy of the profit center in your organization, so your question and you code makes no sense to anybody outside of your company. Please narrow down the issue and create more specific technical question